# How to add through program to the QAT . Program uses c++, mfc mdi

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon, mdi

I have c++ mfc mdi ribbon based project The application when run displays the QAT. We can manually add elements to the QAT when the application is run. When we send the application to other users they have to manually add elements to the QAT.
Is there a way I can add some elements to the QAT from in program or other than manual addition.
I also want to know where exactly the QAT configuration is stored. Is it in the registry if so where in the registry.
Hope I have been clear. Look forward to any thoughts or ideas.
Thanks & Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: Not sure! All I found was this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcribbonquickaccesstoolbardefaultstate-class?view=vs-2019 and I am not sure that is of much use.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think CMFCRibbonQuickAccessToolBarDefaultState::AddCommand should do what I want. When I try will update with my results.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It appears that CMFCRibbonQuickAccessToolBarDefaultState::AddCommand does not do it's job properly. Or its description is confusing. Here is the relevant part: "Second, the Quick Access Toolbar is reset to show only those commands that are listed as visible in the default state when the user chooses the Reset button in the Customize dialog box." So, Will the QAT be reset so that only the commands designated as visible show or not? It's not clear.